# Embeding a Powerpoint in a Web Page

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I've uploaded the pptx file on onedrive and got the embeded link from there.

I've updated it on my html page and everything seems to work fine, but I want it to be autoplayed, instead of keep on clicking next.

And also animation goes messy when trying to keep pressing next before making the animation finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably best off converting it to a series of images and playing it as an image slideshow with javascript.